# What does the "o" of "oSheet" stand for?

Tags: libreoffice-basic, openoffice-basic

I've noticed numerous examples online where OOoBasic & Libre Office Basic use a "o" convention for naming objects.

We always see `oSheet`, `oCell`, and so on.

Does the "o" stand for **object** ? Is there a document in which those conventions are listed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the "o" stands for Object.  It's basically [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

Have a look at [Andrew Pitonyak's Macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php), especially section `3.5. Accessing And Creating Objects In OpenOffice`.  A quick look through the document shows the following prefixes:

- `o` "Object", a very useful type for working with the UNO API.
- `x` is for an [UNO interface](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Using_UNO_Interfaces).  Many of these variables are needed in Java code.
- `s` "String"
- `v` "Variant"
- `b` "Boolean"
- `i` "Integer"
- `l` "Long"
- `n` "number"
- `a` "array" or "argument"
- `m` perhaps "member" of a class or structure
- `c` perhaps "constant"